# Efficient Mathematica Code for List Problem

Tags: computational-mathematics, mathematica, programming

Say we are given $f(m,n)=m \pm 2n + (-1)^n$ where $m>0, n>0$, $m$ as well as $n$ are integers. The problem is to generate a list of all the integers that will not be found in the list of values of the function $f$ for a particular $m$ and $n$.

I came up with the code for the 'plus' sign as

"Complement[Table[i,{i,1,20}], Flatten[Table[$m+2n + (-1)^n$, {n, 4}, {m, 2}], 1]]" - - - (a)

and the 'minus'sign as

"Complement[Table[i,{i,1,20}], Flatten[Table[$m-2n + (-1)^n$, {n, 4}, {m, 2}], 1]]" - - - (b)

After which I now executed

"Intersection[a,b]"

This gave me the result i wanted though it is highly inefficient because as $m$, $n$ increases, the codes take much time. I need $m$, $n$ up to about $10^9$.

I want an efficient code that will be executed once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably belongs on mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Okay, I will post it there too. But ideas about the code i need? Thanks.